# Ubuntu 22.04 - Pulseaudio only showing dummy output

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, output

After an update that announced itself today, I suddenly lost all output devices in Pulseaudio; only the dummy output remains. I don't know whether the update has anything to do with it, but it seems the only logical explanation. The problem is, nothing I have tried to fix it has worked:

- Re-installing alsa and pulseaudio
- Removing the pa config files (~/.config/pulse) and rebooting
- Checking if the kernel has the module snd-hda-intel loaded (it has)
- Checking if my user exists in the audio group (it does)

The situation persists and nothing I have tried worked. Has anyone else encountered this problem? Is there a solution? This is my "jukebox" laptop, so it having no sound kind of ruins the whole purpose. :)

Comment: Did you recently install Chrome Remote Desktop by any chance? This is known to screw up pulseaudio. Running `pulseaudio -k` from command line fixes that for me.

Comment: Hi Anthony, no, I didn't... I have also ran `pulseaudio --start` and `pulseaudio -k`, but without any luck. BTW: only running `pulseaudio -k` results in an error: `E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: 'No such process` `